# Is there a Pathfinder teleport spell to send an enemy some distance away?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, teleportation

From what I can tell, [Teleport](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleport/), [Dimension Door](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door/), [Teleport Object](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleport-object/) and the like only work on willing allies or unattended objects.

Is there a spell to spend a standard action and send an opponent some distance away, if the opponent failed a save? (Besides *Wish*).

I have a distant memory of something like this, but it might have been third party for dnd-3.5e. I'm looking for Pathfinder material with this question.

[Dismissal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dismissal/) has this effect for one **Type** of creature (outsider) in one **Special Circumstance** (not on its home plane).  I can't remember if the spell I'm thinking of was *typed* similarly or not.

**EDIT** Dismissal and the excellent suggestion of [Plane Shift](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/plane-shift) are not really what I'm looking for with this question. I'm picturing a situation where the wizard wants to send a rogue out of his tower, not exile her to the Elemental Plane of Fire. Dismissal won't work on a rogue on her native plane.

Barrier spells are not what I'm looking for here. The wizard wants the rogue gone, not delayed.

I'm familiar with [Teleportation Circle](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleportation-circle/).  That's also not what I'm talking about here. I'm not talking about "The wizard spends ten minutes casting a spell to send an opponent away."  I'm talking about "The wizard spends a standard action and makes a touch attack; if that succeeds, and if the opponent fails his Will save, he's removed to Someplace Else."  My distant memory of this is that Someplace Else is not defined, and it is also not fatal to the target.

This spell does *not* send the opponent into a prison. That spell is called [Imprisonment](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/imprisonment/) and requires a touch attack, a will save, has a long duration and is Ninth level. Alternatively there's [Temporal Stasis](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/temporal-stasis/) that (like what I'm thinking of) removes the opponent from being a threat. [Temporal Stasis](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/temporal-stasis/) does not remove the opponent from the wizard's presence.

---

Answer (score 6):

[Plane Shift](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/plane-shift) (Clr5/Wiz7) can be used offensively. The "willing" clause only applies if you want to transport more than one creature.

[Ice Crystal Teleport](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/ice-crystal-teleport) (Wiz6) also works.

The 3.5e option you remember might have been Trobriand's Baleful Teleport (Wiz6, sourcebook: Waterdeep), which is simply "Teleport, for unwilling targets". Or for very short distances, Dimension Hop (Wiz2/Duskblade2, sourcebook: PHB2).

Answer (score 5):

The lowest-level spell that I've found that does this is the 3rd-level bard spell [***jester's jaunt***](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/j/jester-s-jaunt/) that causes a touched creature that fails its Will save to be teleported up to 30 ft. to a nonhazardous spot to which the caster has line of sight.

The 5th-level sorcerer/wizard spell [***freedom's toast***](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/freedom-s-toast/) is similar except that it can be cast on a subject within close range yet the distance the subject can be teleported is a mere 15 ft.

As this [fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/125066/8610) mentions, quite a few ways exist to teleport others in *D&D 3.5* that simply don't have easy parallels in *Pathfinder*, like the 3rd-level bard spell ***g'elsewhere chant*** (*Spell Compendium* 100-1) and its big brother, the 7th-level sorcer/wizard spell ***Nybor's joyful voyage*** (Magic Books of Faerun Web column ["*Nybor's Small Codex*: Spells from a Former Zulkir"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mb/20041215a)), each of which teleports a subject that fails a Will save to a random location, the former only 100 ft., but the latter a d% miles.

Answer (score -2):

Treacherous Teleport is the spell I think that you are looking for.

https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/treacherous-teleport/

Just add a charm spell or something to get the 'enemy' to do what you say. (A quickened charm person for example.)
Then you cast this teleport spell, telling them to come along. You send them where you want, while you teleport say 5 feet away.

That I think is about as close to a RAW solution to the problem I think that you'll find. If course if you are the DM, and this is a powerful wizards tower. The wizard having some spell contraption to evict unwanted people is perfectly reasonable.